# Procedure for posting questions using the API, v2.2?

Tags: support, questions, api-v2.2

I want use one of the Stack Exchange V2.2 API (e.g. `/questions/add`) to post Stack Overflow questions from my website. I didn't find any app which is currently using the API for posting questions.

As per my understanding, for using write access APIs of  V2.2, I need to register my website domain in the Stack Apps site. Then, I will be provided with the API request key and access token. Then using the access token I could able to use the write access APIs to post questions from outside.

Is there any licensing etc. involves for using write access APIs? Could anybody guide me with the steps/process for using v2.2 write access APIs? Also is there any working example/App which has used the write access APIs for posting questions (e.g. `/questions/add`)?